# Laravel routes with not specified number of arguments

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, taxonomy

I created website where site admin can create new taxonomy terms, rearange them and hierarchize at his will. My question is therefore this: Is there any way, how to handle route with not specified number of arguments?

I am **strongly** against manual solutions like this:

```
Route::get('/{term1?}/{term2?}/{term3?}/{term4?}/{term5?}', "controler@handle");
```

Comment: This would need to be handled outside of the routing scope, I'd think. So your controller would need to split the data out and handle it accordingly. Your route simply needs one `{term}` with `->where('term', '.+')` chained to it.

Comment: [This answer](/a/21526071/1626250) may help you.